# The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition for 'SiteResources'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Ok I have a issue with my resx files for some reason I have this error

The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition for 'SiteResources'

all files are within App_GlobalResources but I keep getting this error

any pointers

Comment: @DGibbs looks like it was just the names of my files, I had like 3 old spanish ones I had not showing in VS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the likelihood even if you have them hidden in Visual Studio that it’s trying to read a file which is similarly named,

If within `GlobalResources` you have more than 1 file try renaming the extension like this

From:

```
SiteResources-fr-FR.resx
```

To:

```
SiteResources-fr-Fr.old.resx
```

(this might still be read)

try changing the extension of the latter so that its complete not a resx file like:

```
SiteResources-fr-Fr.old
```

this will 100% not be a resx file now and should stop asp.net confusing the file you wish to use.

Hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: Seems to have fixed the issue I had some Spanish files not showing in VS thanks @AlanMorton2.0

Answer (score 2):

I ran into that problem when I added a new custom culture on my App_GlobalResources folder but forgot to register it. So I had to remove the file, add the following function in `global.asax`, browse a random page of my web site so the code gets to run, and finally copy the file back into its folder.

```
public static void CreateCulture(string name, string cultureInfo, string regionInfo)
{
    try {
        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister(name);
    } catch { }
    var cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(name, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
    cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo(cultureInfo));  // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object with culture information.
    cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo(regionInfo));   // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object with region information.
    cib.Register();
}
```

In `Application_Start`:

```
CreateCulture("en-gb-custom", "en-gb", "gb")
```

Bonus: don't forget to add full permissions to user IIS_IUSRS on the following folders or the custom language will fail its registration:

- Folder `C:\Windows\Globalization`
- Registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\CustomLocale`

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of an edge case, but we've run across this in our development environment from time to time. We had to setup a custom culture in Windows to support en-HK. Windows 8.1 now supports this culture natively as does Windows 2012 R2, but older machines need to have the culture created. Any machine that does not have this culture setup will get this error reported. The solution is to create the culture on the machine (We have a console app created for this purpose) and everything starts working again.

I reported this answer also on [How to fix "namespace x already contains a definition for x" error? Happened after converting to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035437/how-to-fix-namespace-x-already-contains-a-definition-for-x-error-happened-aft/27849921#27849921)

Comment: Yes. Also note that while most language codes can be abbreviated like "en" ("en-US" is not required), "zn" is not supported for Chinese language, only "zn-CN" is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a some problem.You should write the resources file exactly like that en-US or any country you can check from this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx
I mean you cannot change the string type like this en-Us or US-en because it is special strign. I hope that is helpfull for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is only one GlobalResources.resx file.

try to rename `GlobalResources.Portal-0.resx` to `GlobalResources.Portal-0.old` so it is not a resx file now.

Comment: seems to be the issue iv removed old Spanish files and its fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have resources for different languages. One of them had an incorrect name. Check this page for the correct names of cultures: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Sample names:

- `SiteResources.resx` - default resources
- `SiteResources.af-AZ.resx` - resources for Afrikaans - South Africa

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the culture name you are using is a valid culture name.

For example : sys.pt-eb

The `pt-eb` is not valid culture name so it will throw an error while building the application.

Supported cultures can be checked from

IE-Browser -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Languages -> Add Languages