# VSCode errors :...already contains a definition for...| The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am having these errors in VSCode -> GNU/Linux:

- The namespace '' already contains a definition for
  'GCoreT' [testc]

For this behavior I have read this,

[How to fix "namespace x already contains a definition for x" error? Happened after converting to VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035437/how-to-fix-namespace-x-already-contains-a-definition-for-x-error-happened-aft/17657519#17657519)

but I can not find the solution, that works for me.

---

- The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
  'GCoreT.mapTex(string, E[])' and 'GCoreT.mapTex(string, E[])' [testc]
- Type 'GCoreT' already defines a member called 'mapTex' with the same
  parameter types [testc] void GCoreT.mapTex(string text, E[] add)

.

I think this is the most relevant simplified code.

```
using System;

namespace testc
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           //.. 

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;

class GCoreT{
      ^^^------------------> he says 0


    public Ene[] GTEne (String tex, E[] ene){
    //..    
    mapTex(tex, ene); 
    ^^^------------------> he says 1
    //..
    }

    private void mapTex(String text, E[] add){
                 ^^^------------------------------> he says 2
        //..
    }
}
```

VSCode says:

0

> The namespace '' already contains a definition for
>   'GCoreT' [testc]

1

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'GCoreT.mapTex(string, E[])' and 'GCoreT.mapTex(string, E[])' [testc]

2

> Type 'GCoreT' already defines a member called 'mapTex' with the same
>   parameter types [testc] void GCoreT.mapTex(string text, E[] add)

---

Comment: Are you perhaps referencing an external library that defines `GCoreT`?

Comment: @STLDeveloper `GCoreT` no it is a simple class in de proyect folder, at the same height in the directory tree that `Program.cs` sorry for me bad English.

Comment: @STLDeveloper the code compile and works, but VSCode show the error mentioned, is very uncomfortable. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 21):

Restarting Omnisharp worked for me. Press CTRL + SHIFT + P, then select 'Restart Omnisharp' from the list

Comment: Works like a charm. My Omnisharp was drunk.

Comment: Worked for me I kind of dislike Visual Studio Code version 1.32.3

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried restarting VSCode? Could be worth a try. I have faced a similar issue and the problem seemed to magically disappear when I restarted VSCode. Seems like a bug in VSCode that when you rename namespace in certain cases it clings on to the old namespace name.

Comment: Thanks, 14 months later this bug is apparently still there.

Comment: I had the same issue today in Mac version

Comment: I have the issue too, in GNU/Linux version. Any news ?!

Comment: I had exactly the same problem in Emacs and restarting Omnisharp did not fix it; I had to close and reopen the file in question after restart.