# Getting an error when compiling after Web resource change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, app-globalresources

I am getting this error when trying to run my ASP.NET 4.6.1 C# web project:

```
The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition for 'WebResources'
```

This happened after I've added a new Korean language resource file to the `App_GlobalResource`.

There is only one WebResource.resx file in that directory. I've checked the latest resx file (Korean) and it is generated correctly with public class `WebResources_kr`.

The error points to this file:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\29af3b9e\d233fd91\App_GlobalResources.cuxuxaly.0.cs
```

I tried to rebuild the solution, remove the temporary ASP.NET file but the problem still persist.

**Update**: I deleted the generated code at WebResources.kr.designer.cs, because I see that no other of the languages has this generated, only the main WebResource.designer.cs. I tried to run again, but with the same error.

Comment: This thread should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035437/how-to-fix-namespace-x-already-contains-a-definition-for-x-error-happened-aft#7065387

Comment: It was because I used KR instead of KO, thank you Roman, you saved me hours!